# Use live API or save data locally to own database?

Tags: php, mysql, api

I'm not sure where is the best place to ask this question, so maybe if this is the wrong place, someone can help move this question to a better group?

It has elements of programming, user experience and database, but doesn't really fit well into any one category!

I need to take data and display it in a graph on my site. This data is available from an API.

But I cant decide if it is best to just get this data from the API "live" when needed, or to save data from the API to a local (on my own server) database.

Both methods have pros and cons.

Getting the data live means more URL requests, more latency, and if the site is used by many users, may limit the API access. I 'assume' the site will always be available if using the data live. The API data is also restricted to the past 2000 historical data points.

If I use a cron job to request the data, say once an hour, and save it to my own database, then I am only calling the API once every hour. Accessing my own database should be faster than calling an API from a URL GET request when drawing my page. And if my site is up, then my database will be up, so I don't need to worry about the API site uptime. And I can store as many historical data points as I want to, if I am storing the data myself.

But it seems wasteful to simply duplicate data that is already existing elsewhere.

There could be millions of data points. Is it really sensible to store perhaps 50 millions pieces of data on my own server, when it already exists on an API?

From the user's perspective, there shouldn't be any difference as to which method I choose - other than perhaps if my site is up and the API site is down, in which case there would be missing data on my site.

I am torn between these two options and don't know how best to proceed with this.

Comment: You should definitely cache / store it on your own server: Then you don't depend on the third party for your app / site to function, you easily change how often you want to get the data and you decide how many past datapoints you want to keep. And I don't really see a downside. But yes, it is probably off-topic for SO :-)

Comment: I think saving that kind of data on your own server could be waste of resource, that's why clouding becomes popular, doesn't it?